# Qt - upload to MacOS AppStore from XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

Is there anyone who can upload Qt project from XCode to MacOS AppStore ?

I'm deploying to iOS AppStore from XCode using -spec macx-xcode for qmake.

However, I have problem deploying to OSX AppStore using the same method, it seems that no Qt libraries are copied into .pkg/app file.

Application compiles fine, runs on Mac, passes validation but crashes during Apple Review (can't load QtPrintSupport).

When I export app from XCode I can't see Frameworks directory in Contents.

I can see Qt Framework in XCode in "General" tab under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

I have also tried to Embed Framework in "Build phases" or "General" tab but then there is an error with codesigning "failed with exit code 1" . It looks like it is trying to sign QtPrintSupport_debug

Exporting Qt project to XCode and then compiling and uploading to AppStore works fine for iOS, maybe it should work for macOS and I'm just making some error ?

Best Regards

Marek

Answer (score 0):

Change dir to executable Path And run "macdeployqt" And finished now send to appstore

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you elaborate on that? From what I can see Xcode is making package somewhere in /Library directory not in directory where I have sources. Anyway, purpose of macdeployqt is to copy framework and sign them, right? after running macdeployqt when I hit "Product ->Archive" in XCode does this include Framework into package ?